# Entry of particulate pollutants into the nasal cavity

Tags: physiology, human-physiology, breathing, lungs

NCERT Chemistry of Grade XII (India) writes

> Particulate pollutants bigger than 5 microns are likely to lodge into the nasal passage, whereas particles about 10 microns enter the lungs easily.

I'm primarily a Mathematics student, and my experience in Biology has been fairly limited to high school Biology, so excuse any factual errors that I make during my argument.
From what I know of the respiratory system, the trachea divides further and further getting narrower (into Bronchi, Bronchioles), so how does this happen that particles smaller are getting lodged into the nasal passage, whereas larger particles are getting into the lungs? Shouldn't it have been the other way around?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes indeed, your quote has things backwards. Here is an image and a link to further information:

[ref](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Size-dependent-regional-deposition-of-inhaled-nanoparticles-and-their-interaction-with_fig2_329074423)
[image]
If you follow the dotted line with your eyes - - - - - through the 1Micron grading... On the right side, the majority is absorbed by the head. On the left side, it's mostly the lungs.
[image]
[other references](https://www.google.com/search?q=nasal%20lung%20absorption%20of%20particulate%20size%20microns&sxsrf=APq-WBuLmzVtY0cp_acBcomzExOIrjl_ig:1650444112470&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJla64n6L3AhWJzIUKHRQlC_UQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1897&bih=892&dpr=1.35#imgrc=Ooi8SwLv9zNyHM)